# Call to undefined method when trying to log event in laravel 8.0

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-8

So i am trying to log an event (if it's not successful), but I am always getting this error

Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::single()
This is my code for a controller in the app/console/commands directory.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class FPTrainCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'FPTrain:command';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('EST');
        $FPTree_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $my_array = array("$FPTree_date","association", "test");
        $FPJson = json_encode($my_array);
        $process = new Process(["python3", "public/python/FP_Tree.py", "$FPJson"]);
        $process->run();

        // executes after the command finishes
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
            $date = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

        }
        Log::single("$FPTree_date Error Executing the daily association script");
        echo $FPJson;
        //dump(json_decode($process->getOutput(), true));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The message is very clear: [Monolog Logger](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php) doesn't have a `single` method. Where did you get that method?

Comment: Sorry, brain fart on my end, that was supposed to say: where did you get that error? Which line, what file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single method in laravel log.

According to https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging, these are the function you can use:

```
Log::emergency($message);
Log::alert($message);
Log::critical($message);
Log::error($message);
Log::warning($message);
Log::notice($message);
Log::info($message);
Log::debug($message);
```

Comment: Thank you, now i have to figure out why is not writing the data in the folder where It should store the logs, but that saved me a big headache. not sure where I took the line with single.

Comment: check the file config/logging.php